# Error during Table cache update in vaadin

Tags: vaadin7

MY code is:

```
   BeanItemContainer<TimeCardBean> results = new BeanItemContainer<TimeCardBean> (TimeCardBean.class);
        for (TimeCardBean bean : beans) {
            results.addBean(bean);
        }
      table.setContainerDataSource(results);
      table.addGeneratedColumn("function",new ColumnGenerator(){
      public Object generateCell(final Table source, final Object itemId, final Object columnId) {
      Byte timecardSeq=
     (Byte)source.addItem(itemId).getItemProperty("timeCardSeq").getValue();

     Button btnChange= new Button("Change", new ClickListener() {
     public void buttonClick(final ClickEvent event) {
     TimeCardEditDialog editDialog = new TimeCardEditDialog(viewService);
                            editDialog.init(timecardSeq);
     }
    });
   return btnChange;
}
```

***I get the following error:***

> com.vaadin.ui.Table$CacheUpdateException: Error during Table cache update. Additional causes not shown.
>       at com.vaadin.ui.Table.maybeThrowCacheUpdateExceptions(Table.java:1716)
>       at com.vaadin.ui.Table.refreshRenderedCells(Table.java:1705)
>       at com.vaadin.ui.Table.refreshRowCache(Table.java:2638)
>       at com.vaadin.ui.Table.addGeneratedColumn(Table.java:4404)

Hope you got when I want to express and can anyone tell me about to do this?

Comment: thanks you about your advice..

Comment: your answer is so great..

Comment: Please add solution here as well. thanks