# Vaadin Table "Error during cache update"

Tags: java, caching, vaadin

I may refer to an existing question here on Stackoverflow: [Error during Table cache update in vaadin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24991301/error-during-table-cache-update-in-vaadin)

First things first: I'm using Vaadin 7.5.2 running on Apache Tomcat v7.0.

For some magic reason (and I don't really understand what's the difference between my usual code) the addItem function on a vaadin table gives me an exception ("Error during cache update"). There is an inner exception aswell as follows:

```
com.vaadin.ui.Table$CacheUpdateException: Error during Table cache update.
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.maybeThrowCacheUpdateExceptions(Table.java:1732)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.refreshRenderedCells(Table.java:1721)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.refreshRowCache(Table.java:2654)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.containerItemSetChange(Table.java:4540)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.AbstractContainer.fireItemSetChange(AbstractContainer.java:242)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.AbstractInMemoryContainer.fireItemsAdded(AbstractInMemoryContainer.java:1012)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.AbstractInMemoryContainer.fireItemAdded(AbstractInMemoryContainer.java:994)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.IndexedContainer.fireItemAdded(IndexedContainer.java:627)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.IndexedContainer.addItem(IndexedContainer.java:274)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.addItem(Table.java:2616)
    at com.flowfact.store.components.OrderListComponent.updateInformation(OrderListComponent.java:83)
    at com.flowfact.store.components.OrderListComponent.setOrders(OrderListComponent.java:104)
    at com.flowfact.store.FFStoreController.updateCustomerInfoOrders(FFStoreController.java:202)
    at com.flowfact.store.FFStoreController.updateCustomerInfoOrders(FFStoreController.java:192)
    at com.flowfact.store.components.CustomerInfoComponent$3.orderStatusChanged(CustomerInfoComponent.java:121)
    at com.flowfact.store.components.OrderStatusSelectionComponent$1$1.response(OrderStatusSelectionComponent.java:60)
    at com.flowfact.store.components.ConfirmationDialog.buttonClick(ConfirmationDialog.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:198)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1003)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:393)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:158)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:118)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:313)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:202)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:95)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1408)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:350)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number
    at java.text.DecimalFormat.format(DecimalFormat.java:505)
    at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:157)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.converter.AbstractStringToNumberConverter.convertToPresentation(AbstractStringToNumberConverter.java:110)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.converter.AbstractStringToNumberConverter.convertToPresentation(AbstractStringToNumberConverter.java:35)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.formatPropertyValue(Table.java:4125)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.getPropertyValue(Table.java:4067)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.parseItemIdToCells(Table.java:2349)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.getVisibleCellsNoCache(Table.java:2188)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.refreshRenderedCells(Table.java:1710)
    ... 54 more
```

Some code for you

**OrderListComponent.java:83**

```
    private void updateInformation() {
        Table orderTable = getOrderTable();
        orderTable.setCacheRate(0.0);
        orderTable.select(null);
        orderTable.setValue(null);
        orderTable.removeAllItems();
        orderTable.clear();
        for (Order order : getOrders()) {
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            Product product = order.getProduct();
            Object[] cells = new Object[] { product.getName(), simpleDateFormat.format(order.getCreationDate()),
                    simpleDateFormat.format(order.getUpdateDate()), order.getOrderStatus().toString(),
                    order.getPrice() };
            orderTable.addItem(cells, new Integer(orderTable.size()));
        }
        if (getOrders().size() > 8) {
            orderTable.setPageLength(8);
        }
    }
```

**CustomerInfoComponent.java:121**

```
    orderStatusSelection = new OrderStatusSelectionComponent(getController(), new OrderStatusChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void orderStatusChanged(OrderStatus status) {
            if (getSelectedOrder().getProduct().getName().startsWith("happy") && status == OrderStatus.ACTIVE
                    && getController().checkForEquivalentProduct("happy")) {
                Notification.show(
                        "Sie haben bereits eine Bestellung dieser Art. Deaktivieren Sie diese, bevor Sie fortfahren.");
                orderStatusSelection.setValue(OrderStatus.CANCELED.getValue());
            } else {
                getSelectedOrder().setOrderStatus(status);
                getController().updateOrder(getSelectedOrder());
                getController().updateCustomerInfoOrders();
            }
        }
    }, getSelectedOrder().getProduct().getName().startsWith("happy"));
```

My orders table is initialized like this

```
    orderTable = new Table("Bestellungen");
    orderTable.addContainerProperty(COLUMN_NAME, String.class, "");
    orderTable.addContainerProperty(COLUMN_CREATION_DATE, String.class, "");
    orderTable.addContainerProperty(COLUMN_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, String.class, "");
    orderTable.addContainerProperty(COLUMN_STATUS, String.class, "");
    orderTable.addContainerProperty(COLUMN_PRICE, Float.class, "");

    orderTable.setPageLength(4);
    orderTable.setSizeFull();
    orderTable.setColumnReorderingAllowed(true);
    orderTable.setColumnCollapsingAllowed(true);
    orderTable.setColumnReorderingAllowed(true);
    orderTable.setSelectable(true);
    orderTable.setMultiSelect(false);
    orderTable.setNullSelectionItemId(null);
```

I really hope someone can help me with this;

I'm totally stuck..

Comment: Certainly problem is with price property. Try to print out the price before adding an item.

Comment: Does `order.getPrice()` return `java.lang.Float` for sure?

Comment: Or the problem can be with default value: try `orderTable.addContainerProperty(COLUMN_PRICE, Float.class, 1f);` instead of `orderTable.addContainerProperty(COLUMN_PRICE, Float.class, "");`

Comment: I debugged the Table. For some reason - every - field is "", not null. Also the float column is "". The table works when I initially fill it with data the same way. Then - for some reason - the columns I am giving as parameter appear to be empty strings.

Comment: This is because your default value is empty string, not null. You should have `orderTable.addContainerProperty(COLUMN_NAME, String.class, null);
    orderTable.addContainerProperty(COLUMN_CREATION_DATE, String.class, null);
    orderTable.addContainerProperty(COLUMN_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, String.class, null);
    orderTable.addContainerProperty(COLUMN_STATUS, String.class, null);
    orderTable.addContainerProperty(COLUMN_PRICE, Float.class, null);
`

Comment: @agad please post an answer instead of a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have invalid default value for price column - it should be the same type as the column type, not String. Try:

```
orderTable.addContainerProperty(COLUMN_PRICE, Float.class, null);
```

or

```
orderTable.addContainerProperty(COLUMN_PRICE, Float.class, 0f);
```

Comment: It worked when I changed the default value from "" to null for all columns! Thanks for this.